# Using connection pooling node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, apollo

I am using Meteor.js, Apollo/GraphQL and a MySQL database with the [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysq) npm package as the driver.

I am creating a connection pool as follows:

```
import { createPool } from 'mysql';

const pool = createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'asdfasdf',
  database: 'soundcraft',
});

export function query(sql) {
  // const connection = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(results);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'm not sure what's happening but after a few database requests (equal to the connection limit) it will just freeze and give no error report, and it will stay frozen until the server is restarted.

EDIT: After some reading and finding [this issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/999) it doesn't seem have anything to do with the connection being released, rather it is the fact that the connection remains open by MySQL.

It seems impractical to just increase the connection limit as eventually surely the user will still use up their quota of connections.

It doesn't look like I'm approaching this problem in the right way

Comment: i dont think the problem is in your current code its comes from somewhere else as pool.query  method is a short-hand for the pool.getConnection -> connection.query -> connection.release()

Comment: @AmitWagner yeah, I've read that, which makes it strange. This also seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/999). MySQL will keep the connection up as long as possible. I'm confused as how that is practical as there will be many queries over the lifespan of the application. This isn't even a multi user application but it still has issues.